# Applying Different Image Texture Material to Each Side of the Box in RealityKit

Tags: swift, realitykit

I am creating a box in RealityKit and want to apply different texture to each side of the box. I am using the following code but it always applies the first texture called "lola" on each of the side as a material. Am I missing something?

```
cancellable = TextureResource.loadAsync(named: "lola")
            .append(TextureResource.loadAsync(named: "cover"))
            .append(TextureResource.loadAsync(named: "purple_flower"))
            .append(TextureResource.loadAsync(named: "cover"))
            .append(TextureResource.loadAsync(named: "purple_flower"))
            .append(TextureResource.loadAsync(named: "cover"))
            
            .collect()
            .sink { [weak self] completion in
            if case let .failure(error) = completion {
                fatalError("Unable to load texture \(error)")
            }
            
            self?.cancellable?.cancel()
            
        } receiveValue: { textures in
            
            var materials: [UnlitMaterial] = []
            
            textures.forEach { texture in
                print(texture)
                var material = UnlitMaterial()
                material.color = .init(tint: .white, texture: .init(texture))
                materials.append(material)
            }
            
            box.model?.materials = materials
            anchor.addChild(box)
            arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
        }
```

Comment: I posted the answer. splitFaces = true resolves the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer. The generateBox takes an argument called splitFaces. If you pass it true then it will display different material for each side.

```
   /// The box is centered at the local origin and aligned with the local axes.
    public static func generateBox(width: Float, height: Float, depth: Float, cornerRadius: Float = 0, splitFaces: Bool = false) -> MeshResource
```

Comment: Very useful parameter! I completely forgot about its existence. Upvoted.

Comment: I up voted too, but you should perhaps add that if you split the faces you need to add six materials. Fail to do so and unshaded face will be a odd pink colour.